# automatically open hyperlink of incoming mails

Tags: hyperlink

i want to automatically open hyperlinks of my incoming mails without opening the mail.

i want to develop an addon for a browser or a component for the outlook.

is there a way i can do this. does any one have an idea.

Comment: That sounds like a **big** security risk to me … just my 2 cents.

Comment: +1 konrad. Tibin: just don't do it.

Comment: anyway, sure there is a way to write an addon for outlook, thunderbird and many other MUAs; most of them expose an API.

Comment: Please let us know the name of your virus, er, add-in, so that we can avoid installing it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You must find the documentation for your mail program and read the part about writing a plug in. Plug in can examine mail without "opening" them (i.e. displaying them on the screen).

Note that almost no user will want to install your plug in and if you try other ways (say hijacking computers with a virus or something) that's computer crime. It will take anti-virus producers about two days to update their products to protect their customers from that, too.

So you better have a really good reason for trying this plus maybe written consent of the users. [IANAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL)